# Capture string without conditional ending

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to capture the middle part of a URL, that contains a conditional ending:

A URL can be of two sorts:

```
/a/b/(part/needed)
/a/b/(part/needed)/page/#
```

here's the regexp I use:

```
preg_match('@/a/b/(.*)(/page/\d)?@i', '/a/b/some/text/page/1', $matches);
```

returns

```
0=>"/a/b/some/text/page/1",
1=>"some/text/page/1"
```

It's ok but it includes the conditional ending which I don't want!

Can someone tell me how to not include the conditional string ending in it
but still match when the last segment is present or absent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By anchoring the expression with `^$` and making the first group non-greedy `(.*?)`, you can get the segment you need.  The `.*` alone is a greedy match, and will eat up everything that follows the `.*`.

```
preg_match('@^/a/b/(.*?)(/page/\d)?$@i', '/a/b/some/text/page/1', $matches);
//-----------^-------^^^-----------^
print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => /a/b/some/text/page/1
    [1] => some/text
    [2] => /page/1
)
```

If you don't need the `/page/1`, make that a non-capturing group `(?:...)`.

```
preg_match('@^/a/b/(.*?)(?:/page/\d)?$@i', '/a/b/some/text/more/page/1', $matches);
//----------------------^^^
print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => /a/b/some/text/more/page/4
    [1] => some/text/more
)
```

[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) has good information on character repetition with `+` and `*`, and the pitfalls of greediness.

Comment: + For addressing the root problem - *greediness*.

Comment: wow mate you're wonderfull !! i spent hours on this. I tryed all sort of things on the last part but not in the middle one. Fantastic thanx !

Comment: @Pit it works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Foidac How are you testing it? With or without trailing `/`? Give me a sample url.

Comment: You are right, i should miss something. I'll investigate further.
url can be : 
/goods/announces/search/city/8_paris/type/5_house/price/125000-175000/page/1
or 
/goods/announces/search/city/8_paris/type/5_house/price/125000-175000

Comment: Assuming you substitute `/goods/announces` for `/a/b` in the regex it works: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Gs3Wu4

Comment: Should the `/a/b` be variable to accommodate any `/something/otherthing`?

Comment: i missed something coz now i have it to work fine, with or without the endind part :) sorry mates for taking your time ;) very thanx again and happy new year :D

Comment: @pit Happy new year to you too. Judging by your use of the word _mate_ I suspect you're in a time zone where it's already 2013 :)